# How to have "NULL" instead of "" in export csv file

Tags: csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to have `"NULL"` in export csv file using sql developer .

So now I can do it like this:

[image]

but want to have like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Edit:
Table I'm using and one query I'm talking about (with some data changed):

```
CREATE EXAMPLE_TABLE
   (    "ID" NUMBER(15,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
    "CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "CLASS_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "ATA_CHAPTER" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "MEL_NUMBER" NUMBER(15,0), 
    "MEL_CODE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "MEL_TEXT" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "MODIFIED_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) DEFAULT '$SYSTEM', 
    "AIRCRAFT_GROUP_ID" NUMBER(15,0), 
    "ORDERING" NUMBER(15,0), 
    "EDITABLE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1, 
    "OPT_SCOPE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "REMOVABLE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1, 
    "MEL_PENALTY" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
   )

Insert into EXAMPLE_TABLE(ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION,CATEGORY,CLASS_NAME,ATA_CHAPTER,MEL_NUMBER,MEL_CODE,MEL_TEXT,MODIFIED_TIME,MODIFIED_BY,AIRCRAFT_GROUP_ID,ORDERING,EDITABLE,OPT_SCOPE,REMOVABLE,MEL_PENALTY) values ('1712','TORA','SAD','RUNWAY','SAD',null,null,null,null,null,'$SYSTEM$','521','28','0','SAD','0',null);
```

After Littlefoot select

[image]

- for the first column lack of ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a `NVL` might help, e.g.

```
SQL> select ename, nvl(to_char(comm), 'NULL') comm
  2  from emp
  3  where rownum <= 2;

ENAME      COMM
---------- ----------------------------------------
SMITH      NULL
ALLEN      300

SQL>
```

I used `to_char` as well (because the `comm` column's datatype is `number`). If you don't have such a situation, even better.

---

If you want to enclose all values into double quotes, then concatenate them to column values, e.g.

```
SQL> set heading off
SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> set colsep ','
SQL>
SQL> select
  2  '"' || name        || '"',
  3  '"' || description || '"',
  4  '"' || mel_number  || '"',
  5  '"' || aircraft_group_id || '"'
  6  from example_table;

"TORA"      ,"SAD"       ,""                                        ,"521"

SQL>
```

If you use Oracle 12.2, you can `set markup csv on` and see whether it does any good in your case.

Comment: Could you explain how to use that and what it is gonna do? I see I have also problem with column's which are numbers. If you see on the screen I have ""OpenOption","",,"","",,"$SYSTEM$"," in two places I have ,, instead of ,"", so I assume that's what you talking about

Comment: I dont want to change state of table but only csv.

Comment: Could you, please, edit the question and post test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO several sample rows), as well as SELECT statement you currently use and which produces result you don't want, along with desired result - all properly formatted so that it would be easier to read it. Then we'd be able to assist better, I believe.

Comment: As of changing table data: I'm not talking about that; SELECT NVL(...) affects only what you *see*, not what is stored in the column.

Comment: I put create and insert, but which select do you want? I export whole table, not particular query result

Comment: This "MEL_NUMBER" NUMBER(15,0), provide ,, instead of ,"", in export file

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220415/discussion-between-pqa1222-and-littlefoot).